# What does x* mean in the limit and convergence part of maths?

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, limits

My professor wrote down: $f:D \rightarrow\ \mathbb{R}, D\subseteq \mathbb{R}$, for example for the interval $x*\in D$. We say that $f$ converges for $x\rightarrow\ \mathbb{x*}$ for the limit of $y*$ and it's written as:

$$\lim _{ x\rightarrow \ x*}f(x) = y*,$$ for $f(x)\rightarrow\ y*$, for $x\rightarrow\ x*$ with $x_n\in D \Bbb - \{x*\}$"

Can anyone explain what does $x*$ even mean in this context or in the context of limits in general?

Comment: It's just a notation for "that thing related to $x$, that I'm going to name $x^\ast$." People very often use $x_0$, for instance.

Comment: So if it's written, $\lim _{ x\rightarrow \ x*}f(x) = y*$ i mean that the limit that goes from x to the thing that relates to x of $f(x)$ is something that is related to $y*$?

Comment: So, you have your varinble $x$ going to a point of interest, that you name $x^\ast$. You want to say that as the same time, $f(x)$ (which is "$y$" in the mind of many people, since we usually think of the "$y=f(x)$" notation for plots) goes to some other point, that then you'd name $y^\ast$. You could write $\Lambda$ instead of $x^\ast$ and $\Xi$ instead of $y^\ast$: it'd be mathematically valid and equivalent, but much harder for the reader.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Symbols like $x^*$, $\hat{x}$, $x'$, etc. are just new variable names - they're intended to suggest that they're related to $x$, but there's no concrete meaning. It would be equally correct to have written:

"We say that $f$ converges for $x \to a$ for the limit of $b$ and it's written as $\lim_{x \to a} = b$, for $f(x) \to b$ and $x \to a$ with $x_n \in D - \{a\}$."

The only problem with writing it that way is that it's hard to remember that $x$ goes to $a$ and not $b$, because the symbols $x$ and $y$ have nothing to do with the symbols $a$ and $b$. By using $x^*$ and $y^*$ instead, your professor was trying to make it easier to understand and remember which one is the limit of $x$ and which is the limit of $f(x)$.